# Hide Items from Django Query

Tags: django, sqlite

We have a webapp that has several product names in the django db.  The db is queried for this table(?) and populates a drop down with these product names.  I would like to hide these product names from the query/drop down without removing them from the DB.

Is there a way I can do this in sqlite?

I've inherited the project from a team member who has since left and am 2 days into my learning of Django so any assistance is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you have to use the `Queryset.filter` method when you query them!

Example:

```
items = Item.objects.filter(attribute = value)
```

This will only select items that have `value` for their `attribute`.

If you wan to do it the other way around, you can use `Queryset.exclude`

```
items = Item.objects.exclude(attribute = value)
```

This will only select items whose `attribute` is not equal to `value`.

Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) for more fun with the django ORM!

Comment: I'm still having a hard time.  Here's a snippet of my code     
    /nclass Meta:
        /n/tmodel = ChangeRequest
        /n/tproducts = [(product.name, product.name) for product in Product.objects.all()]
        /n/tproducts = [('', '--------')] + products
        widgets = {
            'product': forms.Select(choices=products),

Comment: I'm added some code below, I'm still having issues.  Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Meta:
    model = ChangeRequest
    products = [(product.name, product.name) for product in Product.objects.all()]
    products = [('', '--------')] + products
    widgets = {
        'product': forms.Select(choices=products),
```

Here's a snippet of my code, 
it returns 
Product1
Product2
Product3
Product4

I'm trying to use the exclude line you provided above and with the documentation but and not having much luck.  How would I get it to return only Product2 and Product4?

I apologize if this is totally incorrect as it's my first time asking a question here.